# Convert google map url to coordinates

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I want to convert this google map url "http//maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=14.674518%2C120.549043&z=16" to just value of latitude and longitude.

Here's my code:

```
$string='http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=14.674518%2C120.549043&z=16';
$regex=' , http://maps\.google\.com/maps\?q=\K[^&]+,';
preg_match($regex,$string,$m);
echo $m[0].'<br />';
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, but i cant do because the url was different from others.

Comment: edit your question to include the information in your comment

Answer (score 1):

There are nice URL-functions(`parse_url()` and `parse_str()`) available in PHP:

```
<?php
$query = array();
  //parse the url to get the QUERY_STRING
$urlParts = parse_url('http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=14.674518%2C120.549043&z=16');
  //parse the QUERY_STRING to get the variables
parse_str($urlParts['query'], $query);

echo $query['q'];
  //returns 14.674518,120.549043
?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That was a big help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added a small change to get the clear result in the above code:

```
parse_str(htmlspecialchars_decode($urlParts['query']), $query);
```